# can't update +1 votes in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why I can't update my votes in database with my radio buttons. I'm not really good in coding but I'm trying my best to figure out but I'm out of luck now.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>vote3</title>
    </head>

    <body>

<?php


        $users_account = $_GET['users_account'];
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password','surveytest');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users_account WHERE username='archievald'";
        $q = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
            $id = $row[0];
            $username = $row[1];
            $password = $row[2];
            $voted = $row[3];
            $acc_type = $row[4];

            echo "<h1>Is he good in english?</h1>";

            ?> 

            <table>
            <form action="" method="POST">

        <?php
            $questions = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE pollid='test'";
        $q2 = mysqli_query($connect, $questions);
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q2)) {
            $questions = $r[1];
            $votes = $r[2];
            $newvotes = $votes + 1;
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            echo '<tr><td>'.$questions.'</td><td> <input type="radio" name="polloption" value="'.$questions.'" </td></tr>';
            }
            if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
                $polloption = $_POST['polloption'];
                if ($polloption == "") {
                    die("You didnt select an option.");
                } else {
                    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE questions SET votes = $newvotes WHERE questions='$polloption'");
                    die("You voted successfully");
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="vote" value="votes" /></td></tr>
                </form> 
            </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

as far as I remember the main problem is in here

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE questions SET votes = $newvotes WHERE questions='$polloption'");
                        die("You voted successfully");
```

Comment: so what is the error you are getting

Comment: i dont get error, but it doesnt update in mysql database row. its still the same 0 count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE questions SET votes = $newvotes WHERE questions='$polloption'");
die("You voted successfully");
```

to

```
$con=mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE questions SET votes = $newvotes WHERE questions='$polloption'");
if(!$con){
    die("Update Query failed");
}else{
    print("You voted successfully.");
}
```

Your usage of `die` is throwing error after execution, which is not good, you can read more about usage of `die` in the following Stack Overflow link: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would he print `"You voted successfully"` if the query failed?

Comment: There we go, looking better :)